# Trying to get nested objects to be given parent ids

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, nested

Alright, So I have `days`, `tracks`, and `events`. When I create a `track`, it is given the proper `day_id` along with its own `track_id` . When I try to create an `event`, I want it to be given the appropriate `day_id` and/or `track_id`.

So when I pull up a `day` it should only show the `tracks` and `events` that as associated with the `day`. An `event` should exist in a `track`, which exists in a `day`.

So, this is basically a calendar that shows a daily schedule of different tracks, and the events within the tracks.

Also, my `events` table in my db has a `track_id` and a `day_id`.

Here is my `routes.rb`

```
      resources :days do
        resources :tracks do
           resources :events
         end
       end
```

My new/create methods from my `events_controller.rb`

```
      def new
        @day = Day.find(params[:day_id])
        @track = Track.find(params[:track_id])
        @new_event = Event.new
      end

      def create 
        @day = Day.find(params[:day_id])
        @track = Track.find(params[:track_id])
        @events = @track.events
        @new_event = Event.new(params.require(:event).permit(:name,:start_time, :end_time))


        if @new_event.save
          flash[:notice] = "Saved"
          redirect_to @day
        else
          flash[:error] = "Error"
          render :new
          end
        end
```

And here is where I am trying to create a new `event` in my `events.new.html.erb`

```
    <%= form_for [@day, @track, @new_event] do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Enter the event" %>

    <%= f.label :start_time %>
    <%= f.text_field :start_time, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Enter a start time"%>

    <%= f.label :end_time %>
    <%=f.text_field :end_time, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Enter a start time"%>
    <%= f.submit "Save", class: 'btn btn-success' %>
    <% end %>
```

Thanks for the help, I'm pretty sure I attached everything that was needed!

Answer (score 1):

You should create the event from the track:

```
@new_event = @track.events.new
```

This will create an event with already the appropriate track_id inside.

Comment: Actually, I thought that worked, and although it created a new event with with the appropriate `track_id`, it made did receive any of the other attributes such as `name` `start_time` or `end_time`

Answer (score 0):

However, this does work...

`@new_event = @track.events.new(params.require(:event).permit(:name, :start_time, :end_time))`